# why `while (base * 10 <= 2147447412)` overflows

Tags: c++

numeric_limits::max() => 2147483647

```
int x = 2147447412;
int base = 1;
while (base * 10 <= x) 
    base *= 10; // this loop will run forever.

while ((long long)(base * 10) <= (long long)(x)) 
    base *= 10; // this loop still will run forever

while (x - base * 10 >= 0 ) 
    base *= 10; // this loop will stop.
```

Question> Why does the while loop run forever? overflow?

Comment: `base` is an `int`. `10` is an `int`. The result of multiplying them is an `int`.

Comment: For your loop to not run forever; you should check for overflow along with the condition. (OR) make x as long type

Comment: @Rahul, `long` is often still 32 bits.

Comment: @chris, LOL, I actually going by C# (long 64 bits). `often still 32 bits` didn't understood for sure. it should be of fixed size .. right?

Comment: @Rahul, It's whatever the compiler makes it, as long as it's at least 32 bits. Note that this came directly from C. You can count on it being appropriately documented per compiler, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, overflow. Once `base` reaches 1e9, `base * 10` overflows. So you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think the point that missed is that in the condition checking of the while statement, when `base` = 1e9, then `base*10` overflows.

Comment: @q That's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I missed the point:)

Comment: In that case, sorry, I missed your point. ;-)

Comment: Please take a look my updated post. The third method works fine which indicates that the code only overflows if the whole expression overflow rather than part of it. In other words, `10 * base` will eventually overflow but `x - base * 10` will not.

Comment: It doesn't mean that at all, I'm afraid. You still have undefined behaviour; the fact that it appears to do what you want us coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code that detects what *would* overflow before doing the multiply:

```
int const kBase = 10;
int const kMax  = numeric_limits<decltype(kBase)>::max() / kBase;

int b = 1;
do {
  b *= kBase;
} while (b <= kMax);
```

Comment: this code has different meaning from the original one.

Comment: @q0987 you're right, missed last iteration

Comment: @AlanStokes yeah, realized the truncation earlier too but neglected to fix it

Answer (score 0):

When `base` is `1000000000` and  `base *= 10;` is done, it exhibits undefined behavior. In your case it seems that it overflows becoming negative.

Comment: Maybe the compiler was smart enough to replace it with `while (true)`.

Comment: Eh, I checked with Clang and GCC. Clang didn't really simplify either, but GCC actually did a number on this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0e0bbb90373105d

Comment: Interesting how GCC optimizes the code.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, the value of `base` will be `1000000000`, which is less than `x`, but multiplying that by `10` overflows, thus the condition in the `while` loop is never met.